# Google search on multi-language site shows description only in one language

Tags: seo, meta-tags, google-search, xml-sitemap

Acordding to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en) I have a site wiht the same configuration, but only for spanish and english:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/en/</loc>
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="es"
                href="http://example.com/es/"
                />
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="en"
                href="http://example.com/en/"
                />
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2015-07-19</lastmod>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/es/</loc>
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="en"
                href="http://example.com/en/"
                />
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="es"
                href="http://example.com/es/"
                />
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2015-07-19</lastmod>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/en/blog</loc>
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="es"
                href="http://example.com/es/blog"
                />
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="en"
                href="http://example.com/en/"
                />
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2015-07-19</lastmod>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/es/blog</loc>
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="en"
                href="http://example.com/en/blog"
                />
        <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="es"
                href="http://example.com/es/blog"
                />
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2015-07-19</lastmod>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

</urlset>
```

My problem is when I search my site using a Browser on spanish, because my site appears, but the description of the site is in English. I pressume that my sitemap is missing something. Anyone knows why Googles doesn't consider the spanish version?

Answer (score 0):

In [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/i18n) (former Webmaster Tools) there's a feature called International Targeting where we (Google) report Hreflang related issues.

Additionally, in the [Sitemaps feature](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list) you can see what errors, if any, we detected for your sitemaps, if any.

In general, hreflang annotations are picked up when both the parent and the target page were crawled and indexed. This may take some time in certain cases, but you can speed that up with the Fetch as Google, Submit to Index feature.